# Getting Monit Web Interface and CLI to work on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, monit, ufw

I have a hard time getting monit to work on my Ubuntu 18.04.4.

I've installed monit via `sudo apt install monit`, then I've enabled `httpd` like this:

```
set httpd port 2812 and
    use address localhost
    allow localhost
    allow admin:monit
```

This is basically the default configuration of monit. Then I restarted monit via `sudo systemctl restart monit`.

If I take a look at its log file at `/var/log/monit.log`, I can see that the monit web server should be running:

```
Starting Monit 5.25.1 daemon with http interface at [localhost]:2812
```

On the server, I have ufw running, output of `sudo ufw status verbose`:

```
root@v22017062828950292:~# sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
2812/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
127.0.0.1 2812/tcp         ALLOW IN    127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 80/tcp           ALLOW IN    127.0.0.1
2812/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

However, if I execute `monit status`, I get:

```
Monit: the monit HTTP interface is not enabled, please add the 'set httpd' statement and use the 'allow' option to allow monit to connect.
```

I've tried binding monit to `0.0.0.0` like this:

```
set httpd port 2812 and
    use address 0.0.0.0
    allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
    allow admin:monit
```

Then I can connect via browser and the IP of my server to the Web Interface, but `monit status` still outputs, that the http interface is not enabled.

I'm currently running out of ideas, since with the last configuration I can clearly reach the web interface from my browser but not via the command line interface.

I also tried disabled ufw with `sudo ufw disable`, resulting in the same problem, that the CLI can not connect to the web interface.

Do you have any more idea, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What happens of you do `sudo monit status`? Where did you put your configuration at?

The monit client must be able to read the configuration to run the status command. It needs to know the port and username/password to connect.  If you properly secured your config with the password, it would only be readable by root.

Comment: Same message for `sudo monit status`. The configuration file is the default location at `/etc/monit/monitrc`. Also, monit is using that configuration file, as stated above, because I can make it work browser access, but not CLI access. So the config is readable.